# Cycles and custom/face weighted vertex normals

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals

I've been experimenting with Custom Vertex Normals lately. Unfortunately it seems like Cycles produces unsatisfactory results when rendering these, especially the more glossy the material is.

Have a look at this image:

[image: sample]

The issue should be obvious in the fourth image, the Cycles Render. There's a sudden, dark gradient at the edges. I've also added the three passes where the issue appears: Glossy Direct, Glossy Indirect and AO.

This seems to be related to Cycles doing raytracing, as none of these issues exist in the viewport, the Blender Eender, Unity or Unreal.

It's happening with light sources, as well as with (only) environment lighting. I tried tweaking various light and render settings and different methods to do the Custom Normals. All without success. They look great everywhere except in Cycles with glossy materials.

I wonder if other raytracers have the same problem? I've tested in Substance Painter's iRay (only environment lighting) where it is not happening (or maybe very very slightly, barely noticeable).

I currently don't have access to any other renderers. If you have access to Vray, Octane, Keyshot or whatever else people use these days and want to test, I've uploaded my test cube as well: https://machin3.io/cycles_fwvn_issue.zip

Any input on this is appreciated. I have no problem recompiling Blender with some tweak or some patch, if that is what it takes, I just need the tweaks and patches as that is beyond what I can do :)

Comment: Did you make any progress? I stumbled upon this method (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAGEGBulzSU) and I'm excited about it! Would be awesome to be able to render it with cycles! I'll try it with arnold and maybe vray next week. Do you know any plugins to speed-up this workflow? Best wishes
Phil

Comment: Hey Phil, I've created a script based on the technique from the video. It takes a model with a live bevel mod, such as created by Hard Ops and once fired, lowers the segments to one, and creates the custom normals using a secondary mesh. I've shown it off here https://twitter.com/machin3io/status/827938829281681410 I'm currently busy with refining DECALmachine and plan to combine these two. Or maybe release it as a separate script. It's pretty simple, so I might actually put it out for free. I think this modiifer method is superior, easier and more flexible than the YAVNE approach for example.

Comment: As for the rendering in Cycles, I've made no progress unfortunately. However I also think it's not that important, or noticable on small chamfers, for what this is intended to be used. It's good enough for me to know that the chamfers + custom normals will look great in the viewport and when seen in engine. Maybe Armory is a potential evenue to investigate in this regard, but before I do, I need the dev to support mesh based decals :) Still if you could test in Arnold and VRay that would be excellent! Let me know how it goes. Also feel free to get in touch via email: human@machin3.io

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. Issue is visible with all raytracing renderers. Blender Render + AO, viewport + AO, iRay, Cycles. It's ok in Blender viewport (without AO), UE4 and Substance Painter viewport. Also check here this amazing GSoC project: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?427746-GSoC-2017-Normal-Editing-Tools

Comment: I've tested it also with 2.80 branch and EEVEE looks ok until... Turning on AO. Clay Render is good. I'm wondering is this issue is strictly connected to AO?